# Roxy Fileman show error when selecting image file

Tags: .net, webforms, ckeditor, roxy-fileman

I am trying to make Roxy fileman work with asp.net webform application (.net 4.5).

So far i am able to upload file but when i try to select the file it show error as alert()

```
"/fileman/uploads/media/4-770x.jpg" selected.
 To integrate with CKEditor or TinyMCE change INTEGRATION setting in conf.json. For more details see the Installation instructions at http://www.roxyfileman.com/install.
```

Page.aspx

```
<script>
    //var roxyFileman = '/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor';
    var roxyFileman = '/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor';
    $(function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('MainContent_CKEditorNewsDetails', {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: roxyFileman,
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: roxyFileman + '?type=image',
            removeDialogTabs: 'link:upload;image:upload'
        });
    });
 </script>
```

**config.json**

```
{
"FILES_ROOT":          "/fileman/uploads/media",
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   " ",
"SESSION_PATH_KEY":    "",
"THUMBS_VIEW_WIDTH":   "140",
"THUMBS_VIEW_HEIGHT":  "120",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_WIDTH": "300",
"PREVIEW_THUMB_HEIGHT":"200",
"MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH":     "1920",
"MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT":    "1080",
"INTEGRATION":         "ckeditor",
"DIRLIST":             "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DIRLIST",
"CREATEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=CREATEDIR",
"DELETEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DELETEDIR",
"MOVEDIR":             "asp_net/main.ashx?a=MOVEDIR",
"COPYDIR":             "asp_net/main.ashx?a=COPYDIR",
"RENAMEDIR":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=RENAMEDIR",
"FILESLIST":           "asp_net/main.ashx?a=FILESLIST",
"UPLOAD":              "asp_net/main.ashx?a=UPLOAD",
"DOWNLOAD":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOAD",
"DOWNLOADDIR":         "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DOWNLOADDIR",
"DELETEFILE":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=DELETEFILE",
"MOVEFILE":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=MOVEFILE",
"COPYFILE":            "asp_net/main.ashx?a=COPYFILE",
"RENAMEFILE":          "asp_net/main.ashx?a=RENAMEFILE",
"GENERATETHUMB":       "asp_net/main.ashx?a=GENERATETHUMB",
"DEFAULTVIEW":         "list",
"FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS":   "zip js jsp jsb mhtml mht xhtml xht php phtml php3 php4 php5 phps shtml jhtml pl sh py cgi exe application gadget hta cpl msc jar vb jse ws wsf wsc wsh ps1 ps2 psc1 psc2 msh msh1 msh2 inf reg scf msp scr dll msi vbs bat com pif cmd vxd cpl htpasswd htaccess",
"ALLOWED_UPLOADS":     "",
"FILEPERMISSIONS":     "0644",
"DIRPERMISSIONS":      "0755",
"LANG":                "auto",
"DATEFORMAT":          "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm",
"OPEN_LAST_DIR":       "yes"
}
```

Not sure why its giving error, when i have to select a file. Upload has no issues..

I am using CKEditor `CKEditor 3.6.2 (revision 7275)` since this is a old application i have had this integrated in webform app.

Not sure what could be the problem as configuration look fine also i looked on internet i could find much related to this issue

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i removed querystring part from path

```
//var roxyFileman = '/fileman/index.html?integration=ckeditor';
var roxyFileman = '/fileman/index.html';
```